# How to run same java project in different systems using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, automation, threadpool

Actually, i'm trying to run the same java selenium automation framework in multiple systems using their IP address. Is this possible in threads using different instances ?

How? is this possible ?

Comment: Do you mean you need to distribute integration tests over a cluster?

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible suppose the automation is written as a test script then selenium instances will be called from python or java. Then you may implement the threading from the test script. This will lead to the script opening a lot of browsers at the same time, then it will need to be executed on a powerful computer, with sufficient amount of CPU load and RAM to support such numbers of browsers.

This is not an usual practice since  the idea of using selenium should be to perform black-box and functional testing. While something that needs threading sounds more like a performance or stress test, which should be done with unit testing codes, e.g. JUnit